# GoDaddy PHPMailer Success but no Email (No errors either in Debug Mode)

Tags: php, phpmailer, snmp

Yet another dilemma with using PHPMailer in conjunction with GoDaddy hosting. The following configuration functioned for at least last few months with no issues, however, out of nowhere, the e-mails are no longer been sent despite having no errors in Debug mode and 'Success' as a Server response. In fact, please take a look at the log file, perhaps, I am missing something obvious?

```
$mail = new PHPMailer. 
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 4; 


$mail->Host = 'localhost';
$mail->Port = 25;
$mail->SMTPAuth = false;
$mail->SMTPSecure = false;
$mail->SMTPAutoTLS = false;
$mail->SMTPSecure = false;
```

Debug result:

```
2016-12-22 12:12:40 Connection: opening to localhost:25, timeout=300, options=array (
                                      )
2016-12-22 12:12:40 Connection: opened
2016-12-22 12:12:45 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was ""
2016-12-22 12:12:45 SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "220-n3plcpnl0096.prod.ams3.secureserver.net ESMTP Exim 4.87 #1 Thu, 22 Dec 2016 05:12:45 -0700 
                                      "
2016-12-22 12:12:45 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "220-n3plcpnl0096.prod.ams3.secureserver.net ESMTP Exim 4.87 #1 Thu, 22 Dec 2016 05:12:45 -0700 
                                      "
2016-12-22 12:12:45 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "220-n3plcpnl0096.prod.ams3.secureserver.net ESMTP Exim 4.87 #1 Thu, 22 Dec 2016 05:12:45 -0700 
                                      "
2016-12-22 12:12:45 SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "220-We do not authorize the use of this system to transport unsolicited, 
                                      "
2016-12-22 12:12:45 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "220-n3plcpnl0096.prod.ams3.secureserver.net ESMTP Exim 4.87 #1 Thu, 22 Dec 2016 05:12:45 -0700 
                                      220-We do not authorize the use of this system to transport unsolicited, 
                                      "
2016-12-22 12:12:45 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "220-n3plcpnl0096.prod.ams3.secureserver.net ESMTP Exim 4.87 #1 Thu, 22 Dec 2016 05:12:45 -0700 
                                      220-We do not authorize the use of this system to transport unsolicited, 
                                      "
2016-12-22 12:12:45 SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "220 and/or bulk e-mail.
                                      "
2016-12-22 12:12:45 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "220-n3plcpnl0096.prod.ams3.secureserver.net ESMTP Exim 4.87 #1 Thu, 22 Dec 2016 05:12:45 -0700 
                                      220-We do not authorize the use of this system to transport unsolicited, 
                                      220 and/or bulk e-mail.
                                      "
2016-12-22 12:12:45 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220-n3plcpnl0096.prod.ams3.secureserver.net ESMTP Exim 4.87 #1 Thu, 22 Dec 2016 05:12:45 -0700 
                                      220-We do not authorize the use of this system to transport unsolicited, 
                                      220 and/or bulk e-mail.
2016-12-22 12:12:45 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO www.#####.com
2016-12-22 12:12:45 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was ""
2016-12-22 12:12:45 SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-n3plcpnl0096.prod.ams3.secureserver.net Hello www.#####.com [127.0.0.1]
                                      "
2016-12-22 12:12:45 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-n3plcpnl0096.prod.ams3.secureserver.net Hello www.#####.com [127.0.0.1]
                                      "
2016-12-22 12:12:45 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-n3plcpnl0096.prod.ams3.secureserver.net Hello www.#####.com [127.0.0.1]
                                      "
2016-12-22 12:12:45 SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-SIZE 52428800
                                      "
2016-12-22 12:12:45 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-n3plcpnl0096.prod.ams3.secureserver.net Hello www.#####.com [127.0.0.1]
                                      250-SIZE 52428800
                                      "
2016-12-22 12:12:45 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-n3plcpnl0096.prod.ams3.secureserver.net Hello www.#####.com [127.0.0.1]
                                      250-SIZE 52428800
                                      "
2016-12-22 12:12:45 SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-8BITMIME
                                      "
2016-12-22 12:12:45 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-n3plcpnl0096.prod.ams3.secureserver.net Hello www.#####.com [127.0.0.1]
                                      250-SIZE 52428800
                                      250-8BITMIME
                                      "
2016-12-22 12:12:45 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-n3plcpnl0096.prod.ams3.secureserver.net Hello www.#####.com [127.0.0.1]
                                      250-SIZE 52428800
                                      250-8BITMIME
                                      "
2016-12-22 12:12:45 SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-PIPELINING
                                      "
2016-12-22 12:12:45 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-n3plcpnl0096.prod.ams3.secureserver.net Hello www.#####.com [127.0.0.1]
                                      250-SIZE 52428800
                                      250-8BITMIME
                                      250-PIPELINING
                                      "
2016-12-22 12:12:45 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-n3plcpnl0096.prod.ams3.secureserver.net Hello www.#####.com [127.0.0.1]
                                      250-SIZE 52428800
                                      250-8BITMIME
                                      250-PIPELINING
                                      "
2016-12-22 12:12:45 SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
                                      "
2016-12-22 12:12:45 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-n3plcpnl0096.prod.ams3.secureserver.net Hello www.#####.com [127.0.0.1]
                                      250-SIZE 52428800
                                      250-8BITMIME
                                      250-PIPELINING
                                      250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
                                      "
2016-12-22 12:12:45 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-n3plcpnl0096.prod.ams3.secureserver.net Hello www.#####.com [127.0.0.1]
                                      250-SIZE 52428800
                                      250-8BITMIME
                                      250-PIPELINING
                                      250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
                                      "
2016-12-22 12:12:45 SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-STARTTLS
                                      "
2016-12-22 12:12:45 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-n3plcpnl0096.prod.ams3.secureserver.net Hello www.#####.com [127.0.0.1]
                                      250-SIZE 52428800
                                      250-8BITMIME
                                      250-PIPELINING
                                      250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
                                      250-STARTTLS
                                      "
2016-12-22 12:12:45 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-n3plcpnl0096.prod.ams3.secureserver.net Hello www.#####.com [127.0.0.1]
                                      250-SIZE 52428800
                                      250-8BITMIME
                                      250-PIPELINING
                                      250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
                                      250-STARTTLS
                                      "
2016-12-22 12:12:45 SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250 HELP
                                      "
2016-12-22 12:12:45 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-n3plcpnl0096.prod.ams3.secureserver.net Hello www.#####.com [127.0.0.1]
                                      250-SIZE 52428800
                                      250-8BITMIME
                                      250-PIPELINING
                                      250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
                                      250-STARTTLS
                                      250 HELP
                                      "
2016-12-22 12:12:45 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-n3plcpnl0096.prod.ams3.secureserver.net Hello www.#####.com [127.0.0.1]
                                      250-SIZE 52428800
                                      250-8BITMIME
                                      250-PIPELINING
                                      250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
                                      250-STARTTLS
                                      250 HELP
2016-12-22 12:12:45 CLIENT -> SERVER: MAIL FROM:<info@#####.com>
2016-12-22 12:12:45 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was ""
2016-12-22 12:12:45 SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250 OK
                                      "
2016-12-22 12:12:45 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250 OK
                                      "
2016-12-22 12:12:45 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 OK
2016-12-22 12:12:45 CLIENT -> SERVER: RCPT TO:<info@#####.com>
2016-12-22 12:12:45 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was ""
2016-12-22 12:12:45 SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250 Accepted
                                      "
2016-12-22 12:12:45 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250 Accepted
                                      "
2016-12-22 12:12:45 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 Accepted
2016-12-22 12:12:45 CLIENT -> SERVER: DATA
2016-12-22 12:12:45 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was ""
2016-12-22 12:12:45 SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "354 Enter message, ending with "." on a line by itself
                                      "
2016-12-22 12:12:45 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "354 Enter message, ending with "." on a line by itself
                                      "
2016-12-22 12:12:45 SERVER -> CLIENT: 354 Enter message, ending with "." on a line by itself
2016-12-22 12:12:45 CLIENT -> SERVER: Date: Thu, 22 Dec 2016 12:12:40 +0000
2016-12-22 12:12:45 CLIENT -> SERVER: To: info@#####.com
2016-12-22 12:12:45 CLIENT -> SERVER: From: Anonymous <info@#####.com>
2016-12-22 12:12:45 CLIENT -> SERVER: Reply-To: Anonymous <info@#####.com>
2016-12-22 12:12:45 CLIENT -> SERVER: Subject: General Enquiry
2016-12-22 12:12:45 CLIENT -> SERVER: Message-ID: <4784799123b2e08d2153a654b78eb1d0@www.#####.com>
2016-12-22 12:12:45 CLIENT -> SERVER: X-Mailer: PHPMailer 5.2.10 (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/)
2016-12-22 12:12:45 CLIENT -> SERVER: MIME-Version: 1.0
2016-12-22 12:12:45 CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
2016-12-22 12:12:45 CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
2016-12-22 12:12:45 CLIENT -> SERVER:
2016-12-22 12:12:45 CLIENT -> SERVER: Full Name: Anonymous<br>
2016-12-22 12:12:45 CLIENT -> SERVER: Email address: info@#####.com<br>
2016-12-22 12:12:45 CLIENT -> SERVER: Phone: ##########<br>
2016-12-22 12:12:45 CLIENT -> SERVER:
2016-12-22 12:12:45 CLIENT -> SERVER: .
2016-12-22 12:12:45 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was ""
2016-12-22 12:12:45 SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250 OK id=1cK2En-001yR0-3J
                                      "
2016-12-22 12:12:45 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250 OK id=1cK2En-001yR0-3J
                                      "
2016-12-22 12:12:45 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 OK id=1cK2En-001yR0-3J
2016-12-22 12:12:45 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
2016-12-22 12:12:45 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was ""
2016-12-22 12:12:45 SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "221 n3plcpnl0096.prod.ams3.secureserver.net closing connection
                                      "
2016-12-22 12:12:45 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "221 n3plcpnl0096.prod.ams3.secureserver.net closing connection
                                      "
2016-12-22 12:12:45 SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 n3plcpnl0096.prod.ams3.secureserver.net closing connection
2016-12-22 12:12:45 Connection: closed
{"response":"success"}
```

Here is the actual PHP file:

```
<?php

session_cache_limiter('nocache');
header('Expires: ' . gmdate('r', 0));
header('Content-type: application/json');

// Include PHPMailer class
include("PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php");


$to_address = "info@#####.com"; 



// Verify if data has been entered
if(!empty($_POST['email']) || !empty($_POST['fullname']) || !empty($_POST['phone'])) {

    $subjectline = $_POST['subjectline'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $fullname = $_POST['fullname'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];

    // Configure the fields list that you want to receive on the email.
    $fields = array(
        0 => array(
            'text' => 'Full Name',
            'val' => $_POST['fullname']
        ),
        1 => array(
            'text' => 'Email address',
            'val' => $_POST['email']
        ),
        2 => array(
            'text' => 'Phone',
            'val' => $_POST['phone']
        )
    );


    $message = "";
    foreach($fields as $field) {
        $message .= $field['text'].": " . htmlspecialchars($field['val'], ENT_QUOTES) . "<br>\n";
    }


    $mail = new PHPMailer;

    $mail->IsSMTP(); // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 4; 


    $mail->Host = 'localhost';
    $mail->Port = 25;
    $mail->SMTPAuth = false;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = false;
    $mail->SMTPAutoTLS = false;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = false;



    $mail->From = $email;
    $mail->FromName = $fullname;
    $mail->AddAddress($to_address); 
    $mail->AddReplyTo($email, $fullname);


    $mail->IsHTML(true); // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';

    $mail->Subject = $subjectline;
    $mail->Body    = $message;

    if($mail->Send()) {
        $result = array ('response'=>'success');
    } else {
        $result = array ('response'=>'error' , 'error_message'=> $mail->ErrorInfo);
    }

    echo json_encode($result);

} else {

    $result = array ('response'=>'error' , 'error_message'=>'Data has not been entered');
    echo json_encode($result);

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`SMTPDebug = 4` is too noisy; `2` is enough for this.

This says you're using an old version, so [update](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/):

```
2016-12-22 12:12:45 CLIENT -> SERVER: X-Mailer: PHPMailer 5.2.10 (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/)
```

Anyway, this is the significant line:

```
2016-12-22 12:12:45 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 OK id=1cK2En-001yR0-3J
```

That says that the message was accepted successfully. PHPMailer's involvement (and any other mailing class) ends here. Next you need to find out where the message is going - first check your spam folder, next ask GoDaddy support to help you trace it, since they won't let you see mail server logs.